# Canvas is already in use even after using destroy() when leave the page and comeback to add data

Tags: angular, typescript, canvas, chart.js, destroy

I am getting the error  Canvas is already in use. Chart with ID ' ' must be destroyed before the canvas with ID 'MyChart' can be reused. The error appears 4/5 times for each particular id in the console.I have already added . **If I stay in the page and add data, doesn't show the error but if I go to another page and come back to this component to add data, the error appears .**

```
if (this.chart){
        this.chart.destroy(); 
        }  
this.chart = new Chart('MyChart', {
    type: 'line',
     data: {
     labels: monthLabels,
     datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Weight',
        data: weightLabels,
        backgroundColor: 'blue',
      },
    ],
  },
  options: {
    aspectRatio: 2.5,        
  },
});
```

Comment: Take a look at it: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/javascript/canvas-is-already-in-use-chart-with-id-1-must-be-destroyed-before-the-canvas-can-be-reused

Comment: hi, it didn't help.

Comment: How about you destroy the chart in `ngOnDestroy()`? This sounds weird as each time you are checking and destroying the chart before rendering the new chart.

Comment: So what is the best approach? Please advise